# How to get the start and end time of a tumbling window?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I get a stream of data that has CreatedOn and UpdatedOn time field.
I need to get a count of Created and Updated records by `TumblingWindow` of 1 hour.

How can I filter CreatedOn to be between the `TumblingWindow` start and end time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited following comments below**

I'll make the following assumptions:

- If a row is created in your upstream system, you get a record with equal CreatedOn and UpdatedOn timestamps
- If a row is updated in your upstream system, you get a record with UpdatedOn different from CreatedOn

Let's say your input records look like:

```
{"rowId" : 123, "CreatedOn": "2022-01-01 00:00:00", "UpdatedOn": null }
{"rowId" : 123, "CreatedOn": "2022-01-01 00:00:00", "UpdatedOn": "2022-01-01 01:10:00"}
```

With the following query you can get a count of created/updated rows per hour:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(hour,-1,System.Timestamp()) AS WindowStart,
    System.Timestamp() AS WindowEnd,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedOn = UpdatedOn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CreatedCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedOn != UpdatedOn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UpdatedCount
FROM input1
GROUP BY
    Tumbling(hour,1)
```

Here giving you:

| WindowStart | WindowEnd | CreatedCount | UpdatedCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01T10:00:00 | 2022-04-01T11:00:00 | 1 | 1 |

Notice how the windowing is done here on the wall clock time (arrival time on the live service, or here query start time when I do a local run in VS Code), so my 2 operations are regrouped on a single window. When running live, if you don't have much delay between the operation time and when ASA receives the row (arrival time), they will surely be in separate time windows.

If you want to enforce time progression on the operation time, you can do so with the `TIMESTAMP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(hour,-1,System.Timestamp()) AS WindowStart,
    System.Timestamp() AS WindowEnd,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedOn = UpdatedOn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CreatedCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedOn != UpdatedOn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UpdatedCount
FROM input1 TIMESTAMP BY COALESCE(UpdatedOn, CreatedOn)
GROUP BY
    Tumbling(hour,1)
```

Now the output becomes:

| WindowStart | WindowEnd | CreatedCount | UpdatedCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31T23:00:00 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01T01:00:00 | 2022-01-01T02:00:00 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: During Create, CreatedOn and UpdatedOn will have the same time. I have seen your post on stackover and had this question. How is TimeStamp() -1 beginning of the window? The TimeStamp is the time of the current event.

Comment: I looked around Microsoft doc and did not find any mention of finding the begin and end of the window.

Comment: I'll update the query later for CreatedOn = UpdatedOn instead of UpdatedOn is null. For WindowStart, when you apply a tumbling window, the timestamp of each event in the window will be changed to the window end time. So at that point, for a window of 1h, the start is system.timestamp minus 1h.

Comment: Query updated to match CreatedOn/UpdatedOn new behavior